# Como guardar un trigger de una tabla A en esquema A en otra tabla B de esquema B?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g

Necesito guardar ciertos datos en una tabla Bitacora cuando actualizo el atributo Salary , el detalle es que la tabla Bitacora esta en un usuario DA y el atributo Salary pertenece a la tabla Empleado la cual esta en el usuario AD, a continuacion muestro el trigger que programo donde esta la tabla Empleado, sin embargo muestra error en la linea INSERT INTO bitacora diciendo que no existe la tabla Bitacora, sin embargo ya le di permisos a AD para insertar en el usuario o esquema DA.

```
 create or replace trigger beforeUpdateSalary
 before insert or update of salary
 on employee
 for each row
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO bitacora 

(id_bitacora,nom_esquema,nom_tabla,nom_campo,fec_cambio,valor_anterior,valor_actual)
values(s_bitacora.nextval, 'AD','EMPLOYEE','SALARY',sysdate, :old.salary,  :new.salary);
END beforeUpdateSalary;
```

Comment: saludos! Intenta hacer un insert normal desde el esquema de AD que es donde se encuentra la tabla Empleado hacia el esquema DA que segun entiendo esta la tabla bitacora. Muy importante hermano! agregale el esquema es decir: Insert Into DA.bitacora values .... espero te sirva...saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ademas de agregar el DA.bitacora debe asegurarse de que dio los permisos para hacer insert a DA con "Grant insert on DA.bitacora to ad;". También la secuencia s_bitacora puede dar problema sí está creada en DA y se está usando en AD, en este caso prueba crear dicha secuencia en AD. Saludos!